# How to use UnityObject2 params with Facebook Application

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I have App on Facebook Canvas, which is build on Unity3D as application for WebPlayer. In `html` loader I can use `UnityObject2` params like logo image and progress bar. But Facebook load application directly from `.unity3d` file bypassing html loader.

So how can I use this params with Facebook App?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found, that it's impossible. I just use `Streamed WebPlayer` described here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/WebPlayerStreaming.html

I create little first scene to load next one, with loading progress; set `First Streamed Level` in Player Preferences to next scene, and wait for `Application.GetStreamProgressForLevel(1)==1`
For some reasons in WebPlayer after loading complete, You need manually Load this level.

It's looks like progress bar in `UnityObject2`.

I hope this is useful to someone.